My Builds Have Been Failing Ever Since I've Added This Redisson Dependency
My CI/CD builds have been running without problems until I added this dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
    <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
    <version>3.38.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

I start the application, run the tests, no issues encountered.
Push the code, then builds fail.
Removed the dependency, the builds succeeded.
All of reported errors are:
IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@5269aa68

Tried to:

Change the version.
Remove the version tag.
Remove the scope.
Change the dependency to include only the Spring Boot starter.

The builds are still failing.
